# Is there a way to access "exports" object in TypeScript modules?

Tags: typescript, durandal

I am trying to use durandal and I need to `getModuleId` by passing the *current* module. My problem is that as I am using TypeScript, the underlaying object which is returned from AMD module seems not to be accessible by Typescript code:

```
export function checkModule(){
       var a = system.getModuleId(??);
}
```

the compiled TS will be converted into this:

```
function checkModule(){
     var a = system.getModule(??);
}
exports.checkModule = checkModule;
```

instead of `??` I need to pass `exports` object which is defined in compiled TS. 
Is there anyway to do that or there is a much simple way?
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is what I use. You are saying "There is an exports variable out there" ... and well there is :)

```
declare var exports; 
var thisModule = exports;
```

Comment: ha! I marked this one as answer as it is more TS-ish than mine. thanks @BASarat

Comment: Is there also a way so that the exports variable is correctly typed and any?

Comment: `declare var exports:any` < I am not sure what you are asking in your question though :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is one way, to cache the `this` in the first call to `activate` method of module:

```
var _thisModule :any;
export function activate(){
       _thisModule = this;
       ....
}
```