# How do I self-reference a module in TypeScript on Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, module, self-reference

I have two modules, 'json', and 'json-object', in JSON, it is a module of all objects extending the default JSON object:

```
import { JSONObject } from './json-object';

export abstract class AuditableJSONObject extends JSONObject {
    // ...
}
```

And in JSONObject, I'm importing the JSON module to mimic the functionality of [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
import * as JSONClasses from './json';

export class JSONObject extends Object {
    public class: string;

    // If class is located, create new object from JSON library and place in new object
    if (JSONClasses[className]) {
        dest = new JSONClasses[className]();
    }
}
```

I'm aware that this is a circular dependency, but this code was fully functional before I started to splinter off my main API project into dependencies for use in other projects. Now the circular code is causing issues when I try to require this package from other projects.

Answer (score 0):

There were no search results for "self-reference TypeScript module", but I figured out how to reference the exports object directly. I haven't been able to test this code at runtime yet, but this is my best lead so far.

[Is there a way to access "exports" object in TypeScript modules?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555506/is-there-a-way-to-access-exports-object-in-typescript-modules)